# Error Loading ASP.Net Profile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-profiles

I have an existing MVC 4 application that uses the AspNetSqlProfileProvider, configured like this:

```
<properties>
    <add name="MyTypeAs" 
         type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[My.Namespace.MyTypeA, My.Namespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]" serializeAs="Binary" />
</properties>
```

Now I wish to update the system (without removing the old profiles) like this:

```
<properties>
    <add name="MyTypeAs" 
         type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[My.Namespace.MyTypeA, My.Namespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]" serializeAs="Binary" />
    <add name="MyHashOfInts" 
         type="System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Int32]" serializeAs="Binary" />
</properties>
```

I have had no problem adding additional properties in previous projects.  If the serialized data was from a previous version where the additional property was not defined, loading that property
yielded default(T).  However, with this change, when my controller executes this line:

```
List<MyTypeA> myTypeAs = 
     (List<MyTypeA>)HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("MyTypeA");
```

an Exception is thrown:

> Attempting to load this property's type resulted in the following error: Could not load type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Int32]'.

Notice that I'm referencing a property of type `List<MyTypeA>` but the Exception says it cannot load the type

> System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Int32].

Did I make a mistake in how I specified the type in web.config?  Is there another cause?

All of this is happening in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 with the .NET 4 runtime selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, different from `List<T>`, `HashSet<T>` requires a fully qualified assembly name.

> System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[System.Int32]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089